# Why was 626 so called before we knew of the other experiments?

Tags: lilo-and-stitch

In *Lilo and Stitch* (2002), Stitch is referred to originally as '626'.  We later (by later I mean a few movies later and several years) find out that Stitch is referred to '626' because he was Jumba's 626th experiment.  At the time of the first movie we do not know about Jumba's other experiments.

My question is **why was Stitch referred to as '626' before we knew there were more experiments**?  Was it the case that it was always known by the writers that Jumba had created other experiments and Stitch was the 626th but it was just not referred to on the screen?

Comment: Why the downvote?  I didn't pick up on this whilst watching the film and I think other viewers mightn't have picked up on the reason either!

Comment: maybe because its super clear in the show it might seem to be general knowledge. Considering in the film it's just an asumption based on two lines of dialogue, have a +1 to compensate :D

Comment: @MacCooper know that you mention it that is a good point. I've edited the question to make it more clear. Thanks for the upvote!

Comment: Just  because _we_ don't know, doesn't mean that the writers don't as well.

Comment: I felt it was common sense, as a child.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it’s made pretty explicit that Stitch was the latest in a long line of experiments. In Jumba’s trial, he describes his work thusly:

> My **experiments** are only theoretical… completely within legal boundaries.

This is immediately shown to be a lie when they bring out Stitch, and we get this description:

> What you see before you is *the first of a new species*. **I call it Experiment 6-2-6.**

That’s why Stitch is referred to as “626” throughout the film, and I think that dialogue makes it clear that there are 625 other experiments.

Answer (score 8):

When on trial at the start of the movie, Jumba is being questioned...

> Gantu:
>   What is that monstrosity?
>
> Jumba:
>   Monstrosity? What you see before you is the first of a new species. I call it Experiment 626. It is fire-proof, bullet-proof, and can think faster than super computer. It can see in the dark, and lift objects three thousand times its size. It's only instinct... to destroy everything it touches! Ha ha ha ha!

It's fairly common to number experiments as opposed to giving them a name. It's fair to assume that there were 625 failed attempts to 'build' the experiment that eventually becomes known as 'Stitch'.

Answer (score 0):

Stitch is based on the Planck Constant (which value is 6.626 x 10<sup>-34</sup>), which is used to calculate the energy produced by a wave.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Could you [edit] it in?

Answer (score -3):

Maybe it is because the area next to the Burbank Disney animation studios is 626. I’m guessing many of the writers and animators live in the 626.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! I believe the question is looking for an in-universe explanation, not an out-of-universe one.